# Running raw sql in php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I am trying to call a stored procedure which I have ran in the workbench and works fine, however I am trying to call this in PHP code and it seems to return an empty array.  I have tried many other methods that hang off the DB class unprepared and raw returns a boolean value.  I have also tried using string concatenation to construct the query as before I was binding, although this made no difference but I thought I would try it anyway.

```
DB::select('call get_oids(\'' . $sysInfo . '\');');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
DB::select('SELECT * FROM company WHERE company_id=?', array($company_id));
```

Comment: I have done this, $oids = DB::select('call get_oids(?);', array($sysInfo)); but this still returned an empty array

Comment: Is this your query .. call get_oids(?);